# How do I get last ID from set of 3 returned rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Guys I have a simple query which is returning 3 rows from table `Notice` (inner join on `Department` table for department name) except for the 3 latest rows (based on Issue Date of the notice)

This is the query :

```
SELECT TOP (3) n.NoticeID, 
    [Subject],
    n.IssueDate,
    d.DepartName AS 'Department',
    n.Body, 
    n.NoticeImage, 
    n.Icon 
FROM dbo.Notice n INNER JOIN dbo.Department d ON  d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID
WHERE n.NoticeID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 3 n.NoticeID FROM dbo.Notice n INNER JOIN 
dbo.Department d ON d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC) ORDER BY n.IssueDate DESC
```

Now what I want to do is, get the NoticeID of the last row that has returned..
For example if the returned Data has 3 rows with NoticeID 25,24,21...I want to get NoticeID = 21 from a query(NoticeID of last row returned). How would I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a sub-query to get the last NoticeID as shown below

```
Select Min(NoticeiID) From
(
SELECT TOP (3) n.NoticeID, 
    [Subject],
    n.IssueDate,
    d.DepartName AS 'Department',
    n.Body, 
    n.NoticeImage, 
    n.Icon 
FROM dbo.Notice n INNER JOIN dbo.Department d ON  d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID
WHERE n.NoticeID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 3 n.NoticeID FROM dbo.Notice n INNER JOIN 
dbo.Department d ON d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC) ORDER BY n.IssueDate DESC
) as T1
```

Comment: I get the id but the column name is shown as undefined.. how do I give the returned column a name? I would usually use "AS 'columnName'" but here, as is already used.

Comment: Select Min(NoticeiID) As ThirdNoticeID From
(
SELECT TOP (3) n.NoticeID, 
    [Subject],
    n.IssueDate,
    d.DepartName AS 'Department',
    n.Body, 
    n.NoticeImage, 
    n.Icon 
FROM dbo.Notice n INNER JOIN dbo.Department d ON  d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID
WHERE n.NoticeID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 3 n.NoticeID FROM dbo.Notice n INNER JOIN 
dbo.Department d ON d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC) ORDER BY n.IssueDate DESC
) as T1